# What are $previous, $owner, and $name?

Tags: extjs

This is callParent method in ExtJS. What are $previous, $owner, and $name? Why is there a leading "$" sign?
    callParent: function(args) {
                var method;

```
            // This code is intentionally inlined for the least number of debugger stepping
            return (method = this.callParent.caller) && (method.$previous ||
                  ((method = method.$owner ? method : method.caller) &&
                        method.$owner.superclass.$class[method.$name])).apply(this, args || noArgs);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's internal detail the class system sets up so it can track methods. The $ are there so it's less likely to conflict with your own property names on the class.